# Can you use two stage least squares (instruments) on an endogenous categorical variable (Likert scale)?

Tags: regression, endogeneity, 2sls

I have an endogenous categorical variable (exlanatory variable) measured on a Likert scale (from 1-4) and I would like to instrument it via 2sls. I am wondering if this is a theoretically correct thing to do since I've only ever come across instruments being used for continuous explanatory variables. To clarify, the categorical variable is derived from a questionnaire where a value of 1-4 is assigned depending on whether the subject answered "Never", "Sometimes", "Often" etc... (Also, note that the dependent variable, Y, is continuous.) I have had no problem implementing 2sls practically (in stata) but I don't know if it is theoretically correct to do this for an explanatory variable that uses a Likert scale and is not continuous.

[image]
Above is a DAG showing the relationship between the variables. I assume all other explanatory/control variables to be exogenous. The red variable freq_experiments is assumed endogenous as it is correlated with unobservables in the error term. (The red variable is the Likert scale variable). I therefore wonder if I can instrument the red variable with the green variables in the normal 2sls fashion and simply treat the categorical(?) variable as having numerical values. Therefore interpreting the final estimated effect as the effect of a unit increase in the Likert scale.

[image]

The image shows the relationship between the Likert scale variable (how often the student does lab experiments) and the dependent variable (the student's score in science). I was wondering if I could instrument the "experiment" variable by simply treating it as taking on a numerical value (i.e. 1-4) where a larger number indicates the students carries out more experiments. Then when I'm interpreting the estimated coefficient, I would just interpret it as the effect of an increase in the likert scale by one unit. Is this theoretically sound?

Comment: Can you supply a causal graph showing the relationships among your variables?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Hi, I have supplied a graph showing the relationship between my main regressor (the one I plan to instrument) and the dependent variable

Comment: Sorry, that's not the kind of graph I meant. I meant a Directed Acyclic Graph showing the causal arrows between variables, which are the nodes, a la Judea Pearl. Can you please provide that?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Hi, I added a DAG showing the assumed relationship between the variables. I hope this is what you were looking for. Thanks

Comment: Good, thanks! I'm less worried about the Likert scale being discrete, and more worried that the Likert scale isn't proportional. Is an answer of 2 really twice as often as an answer of 1? Here's a paper that seems to indicate an IV can be discrete. https://economics.mit.edu/files/6657

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yes...that was also a worry of mine, however because the data is really limited on this topic, I was just going to relax that limitation and ignore it just for the analysis. (This is for a uni project btw so I hope it is okay to allow for it but address it in the limitations/discussion for future research). I'll still try to think if it is possible to perhaps manipulate the variable somehow to maybe reduce the effect of this disproportionality. But anyway... thanks for your help and for the paper, I'll look into that.

Comment: You're welcome! Hope you have success in your investigations.